# Dividing work up between threads? (pthread)

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

I was creating a program to do some maths on some numbers for a school project. Say I have 10 threads but 42 items to process, I want them to process all the items evenly and take on an even amount of jobs. I'm using the POSIX pthread library, I know it's something to do with mutex but I'm not entirely sure.

Here's a simplified example of what I'm doing, however I want to balance the work load out evenly.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int numbers = { 1, 78, 19, 49, 14, 1, 14. 19, 57, 15, 95, 19, 591, 591 };

void* method() {
  for(size_t i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", (numbers[i] * 2));
  }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  pthread_t th[10];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, method, NULL);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This may also depend on the type of process and _items_ you need to process. In any case, make sure to properly create and pass pointers to the items as thread arguments - argument #4 to `pthread_create()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want each thread to process given indices in the table. You don't have to protect the table with mutex as long as you divide work properly between threads so they won't race for the same data.

An idea:

```
/* this structure will wrap all thread's data */
struct work
{
    size_t start, end;
    pthread_t     tid;
};

void* method(void*);
#define IDX_N 42 /* in this example */
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  struct work w[10];
  size_t idx_start, idx_end, idx_n = IDX_N / 10;
  idx_start = 0;
  idx_end = idx_start + idx_n;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    w[i].start = idx_start; /* starting index */
    w[i].end = idx_end;   /* ending index */
    /* pass the information about starting and ending point for each
     * thread by pointing it's argument to appropriate work struct */
    pthread_create(&w[i], NULL, method, (void*)&work[i]);
    idx_start = idx_end;
    idx_end = (idx_end + idx_n < IDX_N ? idx_end + idx_n : IDX_N);
  }
  return 0;
}
void*
method(void* arg)
{
  struct work *w = (struct work* arg);
  /* now each thread can learn where it should start and stop
   * by examining indices that were passed to it in argument */
  for(size_t i = w->start; i < w->end; i++)
    printf("%d\n", (numbers[i] * 2));
  return NULL;
}
```

For a little bit more complex example you can check [this](https://github.com/spinlockirqsave/c/tree/master/threads_cons_prod) and [this](https://github.com/spinlockirqsave/c/tree/master/threads_cons_prod_cond).

Comment: What about getting those indexes, though? :S

Comment: You can do it manually or write some partitioning logic.

Comment: @JustLloyd added example logic

Answer (score 1):

If you know ahead of time (i.e., before starting the threads) how many items you need to process, you just need to partition them among the threads. For example, tell the first thread to process items 0-9, the next to process 10-19, or whatever.